# Bootstrap toggle doesn´t work when a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The navbar on the right collapses when the window is resized, but when I click the toggle button the menu appears. When I click any link, the bar doesn´t "un-toggle"... Can anybody help me?

[image: Screenshot]

Site [here](http://firenetworks.eu/abc6/index.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the menu collapse when a link is clicked is not the default functionality of the expand/collapse menu with bootstrap.  If you want it to function that way, you have to bind the hide function `.collapse('hide')` to the click action for those links.

You can do so by including this:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a').click(function() {
        $('.navbar-default .navbar-collapse').collapse('hide')
    });
});
```