# Hide bootstrap menu when the link is being clicked

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, menu, navbar

So when the responsive menu is opened, I click on the anchor link, and the menu remains open, but my goal is to make it close, so I can click again the menu button menu opens again and I click for example another link.

Html:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="navbar-header">         
                                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="menu_li link_anchor collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
                                    <ul class="dropdown1">
                                        <li><a class="link_close" href="#products_anchor">Продукция</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#opport_anchor">Преимущества</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#clients_anchor">Клиенты</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#maps_anchor">Контакты</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>                              
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I tried this JS code, it hides the list of links which are menu elements, but hides forever. I click the menu button againg and the menu does not show anymore:

```
$("#menu a").click(function() {
    var menu = $(this).closest("#menu");
    $(menu).css('display','none');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(menu).css('display','');
    },200);
    });
```

Comment: SOLVED

Thanks to this guy:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21868414/bootstrap-toggle-doesn%C2%B4t-work-when-a-link-is-clicked?rq=1